# Rewrite URL in WordPress generates 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite this kind of url:

`http://www.xyz.pl/program-tv/?polsat`

To this url:

`http://www.xyz.pl/program-tv/polsat`

I created some code in .htaccess that rewrite my old url, to desired one. But it generates:

`404 Not found error`

This is what i have so far, do you have any tips what I'm doing wrong? It's fault of the WordPress or my code?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** > **Permalinks**, and save them (even if you didn't change anything). That should refresh the URLs of your Wordpress.

Comment: When this two rules: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$` 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1%1? [R=301,L]` are added and saved in `.htaccess` i can't save them. Cuz when i click `save` in `admin panel` i got `404 error` as well